# MySQL apostrophes ' errors

Tags: php, mysql

How would I go about inserting apostrophes ' into MySQL without it throwing any errors in PHP. What would be the proper way to echo them out from MySQL too.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to make work.

Comment: See [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) assuming you are using the `mysql_` functions.  What are you using (mysql_*, Mysqli, or PDO)?

Comment: Or you can use PDO, and sidestep the issue neatly.

Comment: Well it's a form with user submitted text and when they use ' they get a error. So in short so no one can inject anything bad and or so they don't get a error I just remove it with str_replace

Comment: Yeah, see any answer which mentions the escape functions... And please, for the benefit of future discoverers of this question, and in as many of your questions as reasonable; include example code.

Comment: I think a major problem is that people think the tick `'` is an apostrophe. It's not. A proper in-text apostrophe is unicode value `U+2019` while the tick is unicode value `U+0027`. You can just search through the text and replace these to take care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider both PHP and MySQL, and if you are using a framework, that too.

As far as PHP is concerned, you need to use the opposite style of quote from those contained in your string, or else "escape" them, like this:

```
$string = 'this is not a problem; it\'s escaped.';
$string = "I don't need to escape";
```

As for MySQL, you should use an escaping function, like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or similar.

There is a more advanced technique for using user-supplied data in queries called "prepared statements", which is the most robust and safe way to achieve dynamic queries with user-supplied parameters. See [this section of the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared queries, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) might be best. You wont need to worry about escaping your inputs then.

Answer (score -1):

In php you escape apostrophies with a backslash.

Comment: Use the API function provided by the MySQL extension being used, never try to manually escape using addslashes or anything like that.  Or use prepared statements or parameterized queries so the escaping is done for you.